# why does not show the view content in template with {{ xxx }}

Tags: python, django

I want do learn & practice python w Django. Therefore I am trying to Code a simple app, translating some text from DE to EN and give the EN text to index.html. But the view content {{ eng_text }} does not Show up in the html template.

This is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from textblob import TextBlob

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

DEtext = 'das ist ein deutscher text, der übersetzt werden soll'
print (DEtext)

def translate(request):
    tb = TextBlob(DEtext)
    ENtext = tb.translate(to="EN")
    print(ENtext)
    dict = {'eng_text': DEtext}
    return render(DEtext, 'index.html', context=dict)
```

Comment: How does this even work? The first argument to `render` should be `request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works well.

```
DEtext = 'das ist ein deutscher text, der übersetzt werden soll'

def index(request):
    tb = TextBlob(DEtext)
    ENtext = tb.translate(to="en")
    dict = {'eng_text': ENtext}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read: [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

The first argument to `render` should be `request`.

---

Change:

```
return render(DEtext, 'index.html', context=dict)
```

To:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context=dict)
```

Comment: many thanks. I was blind and thinking of type issues due to TextBlob. :-)

Comment: last Question regarding this: I put the Code inside the 'index' view. What do I need to consider when I want to use the view 'transate'? This does not work at the Moment.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand completely. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: the translate function does not work, despite the above correction. it only works when I move in the Code into de index function. do I need to define a url for the transate function?

Comment: Yes, you need a url which points to this view. So that, when you visit that url, this view gets executed.